# Scraping with login

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a site using python-requests, but cannot seem to login using the code below:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
data = {'j_username': 'name@gmail.com'}
session.post('http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/login.jsp', data=data)
r = session.get('http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/genesets.jsp?
collection=CP:BIOCARTA')
print(r.content)
```

I don't believe I am doing anything wrong here, though, as I followed some posts online.

Comment: It is probably because of the data you are posting, you are only posting your email, without a password, and the website might probably require other data aswell.

Comment: it does not require a password, only an email

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login to website via Python Requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665226/login-to-website-via-python-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to figure out what does it need is open the debugger console and click on network tab ,and see what happens when you fill the email and click on login. Yes  it takes email only but  internally it is also sending the another parameter.

See this :you can see what are the paramters you need and with what name:
[image]
You need to pass:
**j_username and j_password:'password'** where j_username is the username you typed.

Another problem is :
your post request should be passed with data here:
**`http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/j_spring_security_check`**

[image]

IT  looks like you dont know how to use inspect element .All the images are from inspect window.Use that

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden input field in the login page which is 'j_password' and its value is constant 'password'. And you should not post to login.jsp, but post to that url: http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/j_spring_security_check

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
data = {'j_username': 'name@gmail.com', 'j_password': 'password'}
session.post('http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/j_spring_security_check', data=data)
r = session.get('http://www.broadinstitute.org/gsea/msigdb/genesets.jsp?collection=CP:BIOCARTA')
print(r.content)
```

I use a program called [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to help me see what happens in the background. It is really helpful!